# Encryption algorithm published with MSR606 Magnetic Stripe Card Reader/Writer Programmer's Manual

Tags: escaping, encryption, magnetic-cards

I have the following manual for MSR206 Progammers.

http://www.ylk-ic.com/MSR606%20Programmer%27s%20Manual.pdf

In the given manual,

ABC123

has been converted to **C5B07814954E3E2A**
 and 12345 has been converted to **2B8849EAAF**.

The encryption algorithm is stated in Page: 12 and 24.

Please help me figure it out.

I want to write for example "HELLO" in Track 1 and **896** in track 2 and 3.

Comment: I don't want to sign up for facebook, just to help you ;-)

Comment: @septi: Fixed that for you. :)

Comment: What makes you think this is encryption? It just looks like it's encoding ASCII characters into bytes.

Comment: @Adam: what made you think that it's just ASCII? have you looked at the manual? If it is exactly the ASCII character codes then is %ABC123; to C5B07814954E3E2A justifiable?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said *characters* to bytes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually encoding from ASCII into those hex strings appears to be only necessary if you use the raw write command.  It is much easier to use the write command described on page 15 of the PDF, which takes ASCII directly.  For your example data, the complete command would be:

```
0x1b 'w' 0x1b 's' 0x1b 0x01 'H' 'E' 'L' 'L' 'O' 0x1b 0x02 '8' '9' '6' 0x1b 0x03 '8' '9' '6' '?' 0x1c
```

Comment: @DizitalTech may I ask you how you did it ? I always get "command format error" (2) when using write ISO (w) ...